# Sharing music Service with 2 activities

Tags: android, media-player, android-service

I have a Fragment[1] which plays music with service and shows the progress of song like duration,songname etc. Now when I click of the albumart of song currently played, I need to show another screen[2] with music playing in with the same service and progress. For passing values from [1] to [2], I am using Intent .But both [1] and [2] are not in sync.How could I make [1] and [2] both show and play same song,duration etc. what changes should I make in [1] and [2] both. I am calling service class in both [1] and [2].
**EDIT** I am creating service both in [1] and [2]. is this the right way to do it?

Code in [1] :

```
imgAlbumArt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent testIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),PlayScreen.class);
            testIntent.putExtra("currentDur",currentDuration);
            testIntent.putExtra("totalDur",totalDuration);
            testIntent.putExtra("progress",progress);


            startActivity(testIntent);

        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
Tried using broadcast receiver.

```
 public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("test"))
    {
         Bundle extra = intent.getExtras(); 
         String title = extra.getString("title");
         Log.d("RECEIVER","boradcast receieved wt title"+title); 
    }
```

Now how to use this title value in [2]???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to share data between fragments and you  only need one playerservice that holds all the player info and publish this info to any subscriber you want like fragments or activities.

To publish the info you could use BroadcastReceiver 
 or if you want to learn something more powerfull I recomend you Observable class of rxjava.

Comment: So you mean I need not call service again in [2]? Can you please give an example how can I do it using receiver.

Comment: you subscribe to service notifications in fragments, the service can or not be started. If you want to start playing a song for instance you call startService method. There is a lot of tutorials using BroadcastReceiver, search!!!!

Comment: Please check my edited code. I am sending the broadcast from service class and the receiver receives it. Now how should I send it to [2]? Using intents? And in [2] if I am not creating service again my service variable would be null inside [2]. So how could I get the non null service value to continue music

Comment: Can you please suggest how could I get the service value so that I need not start service again in 2nd activity [2].

Comment: You should read a lot about Service lifecycle. startService only is called if the service is not started yet.

Comment: Successfully implemented using broadcast receiver. Thanks a lot.